# ¿Cómo mostrar imagen desde una URL en python-docx-template(docxtpl)? Django Python

Tags: python, django, docx, python-docx

Estoy usando python-docx-template (docxtpl) el cual por medio de una plantilla `.docx` permite generar un documento `.docx` tengo una función donde se crea el documento:

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate, InlineImage
from docx.shared import Mm

def generaraDocumento(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/msword')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="cv.docx"'

    doc = DocxTemplate(str(settings.BASE_DIR) + '/cv_api/templates/docx_filename.docx')
    imagen = docente['foto_web_low'] 
    myimage = InlineImage(doc, image_descriptor=imagen, width=Mm(20), height=Mm(10))

    context = {'myimage': myimage}

    doc.render(context)
    doc.save(response)

    return response
```

Mando en el `context` una imagen que tengo en una url del servidor, pero al momento de generarse el documento me sale solamente la dirección de la URL y no la imagen en si, en mi plantilla me devuelve esto:

```
https://sica.utpl.edu.ec/media/uploads/docentes/fotos/web/low/1102904313_low.jpg
```

En mi plantilla `.docx` tengo esto para mostrar la imagen:

```
{{ myimage }}
```

Deseo mostrar la imagen, he probado varias cosas pero no me presenta la imagen en mi plantilla. Como puedo hacer para presentar la imagen?

Comment: no deberías de obtener la imagen convertirla en base64 para luego remplazarla???

Answer (score 0):

En la parte superior importa os y setting de django

```
import os
from django.conf import settings
```

La linea donde está tu variable imagen ponla de la siguiente forma

```
imagen = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, docente['foto_web_low'])
```

Ya con eso te sale la imagen en el archivo .docx

Comment: Ya la edité, quedo mejor me parece, jjjjj